# How to Display Earliest Time

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am having the toughest time finding how to get ONLY the earliest time to show in the Summary Tab. Currently I have a pivot table on the Summary tab with All Data selected from Report Tab. The Report tab gets the information from the Data tab. I have trying using MIN but I'm not sure that is the best method. Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

[Report Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSrkx.jpg)

[Summary Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6zSA.jpg)

[Data Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQaQR.jpg)

Comment: You need any extra information apart from this.?

Answer (score 0):

`MIN` is in fact the best function so far for this. Best if you can reference this not on the pivot table, but on the source data set to ensure no mis-referencing when pivot structure changes.

If you're doing this with a pivot table, using the value filters functionality would do the trick. You just select the 'bottom 1' of the list of time values you have.